# Null Pointer Exception if changing toolbar icon on observe? Facing problem with kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, mvvm, viewmodel, android-livedata

Having a filter Fragment A with custom toolbar which is used commonly for many fragments and activity for filter list on click of filter icon of toolbar opening Fragment B to set filter option and and observing filter option using ViewModel and Live data . and opening Fragment A from any where but some times filter icon getting updated according to selected filter and sometimes throwing null pointer for imageview . any suggestion and help most welcome and thanks in advance .

I had tried to remove observers but didn't worked .
Image view already present in xml .
Tried Delay using handler. but still getting same error
Expecting some better and helpful solution.

Comment: Code? Stacktrace?

Answer (score 0):

This is fixed now .
Problem was Observing data before loading fragment without null

"?" safety